# Items Padding showing Different,also after same padding size in Windows Application c#

Tags: c#

```
listBox1.Items.Add(item.PadRight(60) + "Quantity=" +  txtteesqty.Text.PadRight(60) + "RS=" + tea_total);

listBox1.Items.Add(sb.ToString().PadRight(60) + "Quantity=" + txtomelteqty.Text.PadRight(60) + "RS=" + omelte_total);
```

both **'item'** and **'sb.tostring()'** character lenght is same which is '23' but on the listbox both listitem not at the **same position**.

I really Dont know whats going on why it is not at same padding Help me!

Comment: What about the lengths of `txtteesqty` and `txtomelteqty`? Can you please provide a screenshot of the problem, or the rendered code output? Have you inspected the element with F12 to both check for error messages, and see if additional padding is being applied?

Comment: If they have different values it's not surprising they do not align as an "i" and an "m" have the same length (1) but different widths. You could use a mono-spaced font like Consolas or Courier New where each character has the same width as a quick(-and-dirty) solution..

Comment: you need use [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Thx @ckuri its work by changing text style